# writing the a local file using parameters on command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a little project thing to get my javascript skills up. The goal is for, when using `curln`, the `.cmd` file will write `%~dp0\#temp` with the `curl %1` (the curled html result of the first parameter)

expected with `curln "https://www.google.com"`: (long html)
actual: "`<< was unexpected at this time.`"

I have tried looking things up, this was a mesh of what I found online. I have tried using `<` and `<<` as, a beginner, I don't understand the difference.

Code:

```
%~dp0\#temp << cmd curl %1
```

I would like the output of curl to be written to the current directory's (`%~dp0`) file named `#temp`. `%1` is a preset `*.cmd` parameter variable that is shown in this example:
`example "this is %1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` and `>>` are output. The first creates a new file, the second appends to an existing file. `<` is input. It accepts input (reads) into a program from another source, which is typically a file or the output of another program. It doesn't work with writing to files.

You're most likely looking for `curl %1 >>"%~dp0#temp"` instead. You don't need the cmd in front of it, as you're already in a command window when the batch file executes.

Comment: @Compo: Corrected. Note that I just used the OP's code directly, changing the order around some. I didn't write the code.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple transfer I use repeatedly using curl the minimal call is

`curl -o "%~dpnx0" remote.url`

That ensures the fileName and eXtension are saved in the current DrivePath

There is no error checking or security communication so is only useful for a single .html or .js or .pdf etc.

Thus a complex call can run to dozens of lines.